# Alternative metric space proof for $d(x,y)\geq 0$

Tags: alternative-proof

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) describes a metric space as $(M,d)$, where $M$ is a set and $d(x,y)$ is a metric. The axioms are as follows:

$d : M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$d( x, x) = 0$

$d( x, y ) = d ( y, x )$

$d( x, z ) \leq d( x, y ) + d( y , z )$

A proof of $d(x,y)\geq 0$ is provided as follows:

**Proof 1** (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space))

(1) $d(x,y)+d(y,x)\geq d(x,x)$ by triangle inequality

(2) $d(x,y)+d(x,y)\geq d(x,x)$  by symmetry

(3) $2 \times d(x,y)\geq 0$  by identity of indiscernibles

(4) $d(x,y)\geq 0$  we have non-negativity

It seems to me that a model of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is included in the metric space axioms and proof.
I assume that the reasoning from (3) to (4) is provided by division by 2 over the inequality of two real numbers .

**Proof 2** represents a variation of **Proof 1**, were step (3) differs from **Proof 1**.

**Proof 2**

(1) $d(x,y)+d(y,x)\geq d(x,x)$ by triangle inequality

(2) $d(x,y)+d(x,y)\geq d(x,x)$  by symmetry

(3) $d(x,y)+d(x,y)\geq 0$  by identity of indiscernibles

(4) $d(x,y)\geq 0$  by  $\forall z \in \mathbb{R} \bullet((z + z) \geq 0) \Rightarrow (z \geq 0))$

Is the rule used to infer  (4) from  (3) valid? If it is,what property of real numbers is being invoked?

The reason I am using $((z + z) \geq 0) \Rightarrow (z \geq 0))$ instead of $((2 * z) \geq 0) \Rightarrow (z \geq 0))$ is that I can get the former, but not the latter, to work in a theorem prover.

Comment: "I[t] seems to me that a model of real numbers R is included in the metric space axioms"  It's in the *definition*.  $d:\mathbb M \times M \to \mathbb R$ so *by definition* $d(x,y)$ is a real number.  Note, all the arithmetic and ordering and algebra you are doing is in $d(w,u)$ values in $\mathbb R$.  We are doing *nothing* in the space $M$ itself except comparing whether two values are equal or not.

Comment: By the way.  It strikes me you are missing the axiom that if $x \ne y$ then $d(x,y) \ne 0$.  You could, with the axioms given, have a metric space where $d(x,y) =0$ always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I[t] seems to me that a model of real numbers R is included in the metric space axioms"

It's in the *definition*.  $d:\mathbb M \times M \to \mathbb R$ so *by definition* $d(x,y)$ is a real number.  Note, all the arithmetic and ordering and algebra you are doing is in $d(w,u)$ values in $\mathbb R$.  We are doing *nothing* in the space $M$ itself except comparing whether two values are equal or not.

> Is the rule used to infer (4) from (3) valid? [$(x+x) \ge 0 \implies x \ge 0$]

If $x < 0$ then $x+x < 0 + x$ (axiom: if $a < b$ then for all $x$, $a+x< b+x$.)

So $x + x < x$ and $x < 0$. So $x+x < 0$ (by transitivity).

By trichotomy this contradicts $x + x \ge 0$.

So if $x + x \ge 0$ then $x < 0$ is impossible.  So by trichotomy $x > 0$ or $x = 0$.

......

The second proof is sidestepping (why I don't know) the algebraic natural of the reals.

$x + x = 2x$ ("Why?  Well, that's for the algebra class... I'm teaching metric spaces, so I dont know.... I guess")

And $2x \ge 0\implies x \ge 0$ (ditto)

To avoid the issue it uses a more basic abstract idea.

....

I'm being a little facetious but $1 + 1 = 2$ and $x + x =2x$ by definition and by distributions.  But proving $2> 0$ and that $2 > 0\implies \frac 12 > 0$ is *not* trivial.  (It's not hard but it's not trivial). So the issue really is Which Framework of Axioms are you applying.  Can we assume "basic algebra" (in which case $x + x = 2x$ and $2> 0$ and $2x \ge 0 \implies x \ge 0$ is all obvious and acceptable)?  Or are we assuming nothing but what we have been given (then we must prove $x + x \ge 0\implies x \ge 0$).

....

But in any event.  $d(w,u)$ *IS* a real number and *all* of these are real number arithmetic.

If $d(x,y)=n$ is a integer and $d(x,y)$ is not a perfect square then $\sqrt{d(x,y)}$ is irrational.

That is a valid (albeit it irrelevant and non-analytical) observation.

....

And to save you trouble ahead, when asked to prove that that by notation: $x\cdot x\cdot .... \cdot x = x^m$ where $x$ is some abstract space and $\cdot$ is abstract associative binary operation on $X$, and you are asked to prove $x^mx^n = x^{m+n}$..... $m,n$ *are* integers and $+$ *is* addition, and $m+n$ *does* mean "take $m$ things and then continue with $n$ more things" and simplying saying "$\cdot$ is associative; so performing an opperation $m$ times ant then another $n$ times so you did it $m+n$ times is the same as performing it $m$ times and then perfoming it $n$ times and performing the operation on the results" *is* a proof.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the rule you're using for $(3)\to (4)$ as $(2x\geq 0\implies x\geq 0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This is just a fundamental fact about multiplication by a positive number.